# Android Grid Layout?

Tags: android, layout, grid

I'm trying to build a layout like the one in the image. Every little square represents a quarter of an hour and a big square (4 little squares) represent an hour.

I can't quite figure it out how can I build this view. Any suggestions? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested `GridLayout`s should help. But this will eat up resources.

UPDATE: On a second thought, with more complicated styling, you should do with one `GridLayout`.

Comment: could you please provide a code sample? I've tried using a Gridlayout but I can't quite figure it out how I can build this!

Comment: That depends. Those "squares" - are they buttons or are they some passive indicators?

Comment: The squares can be some sort of buttons - where users can interact with. Basically a user can schedule an appointment ( 1/4 hour = 1 square)